# Tomcat9 Failed at step NAMESPACE

Tags: linux, tomcat, server, debian, systemctl

My OS is Debian 10 (Buster), 4.19 kernel, and Tomcat9 seems to be unstable.

I don't want to see any error messages when I run the 'systemctl status tomcat9.service' command.

but, 'systemctl status tomcat9.service' command is print an error message.

```
● tomcat9.service - Apache Tomcat 9 Web Application Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tomcat9.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-03-03 21:02:15 KST; 12min ago
     Docs: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/index.html
  Process: 25999 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-update-policy.sh (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)

Mar 03 21:02:15 doonas.com systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat 9 Web Application Server...
Mar 03 21:02:15 doonas.com systemd[25999]: tomcat9.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: No such file or directory
Mar 03 21:02:15 doonas.com systemd[25999]: tomcat9.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-update-policy.sh
Mar 03 21:02:15 doonas.com systemd[1]: tomcat9.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
Mar 03 21:02:15 doonas.com systemd[1]: tomcat9.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 03 21:02:15 doonas.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat 9 Web Application Server.
```

However, despite the error message, I have confirmed that the webpage is working properly.

I don't know why this is happening.

I tried to solve the problem.

1. shutdown.sh, startup.sh have been activated.

but, it still doesn't work.

```
root@doonas:/usr/share/tomcat9/bin# bash shutdown.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat9
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat9
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat9/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat9/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/jav                                                                                     a.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Mar 03, 2020 9:14:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: No shutdown port configured. Shut down server through OS signal. Server not shut down.
root@doonas:/usr/share/tomcat9/bin# bash startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat9
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat9
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat9/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat9/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

2. I modified the symbolic link by referring to the [this link](https://salsa.debian.org/java-team/tomcat9/blob/master/debian/README.Debian).

He said "Tomcat is sandboxed by systemd and only has write access to the following directories"

but, it still doesn't work.

```
root@doonas:/var/lib/tomcat9# ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Mar  3 21:00 conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat tomcat 4096 Jun 14  2019 lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root     16 Mar  3 20:48 logs -> /var/log/tomcat9
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Feb 18 13:31 policy
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root     19 Mar  3 20:48 work -> /var/cache/tomcat9/
root@doonas:/var/lib/tomcat9# ls -l conf/Catalina
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Mar  3 21:00 conf/Catalina -> /etc/tomcat9/Catalina
```

Here's my Tomcat9 information.

CATALINA_BASE is /usr/share/tomcat9.

```
root@doonas:/usr/share/tomcat9# ls -l
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 17 10:37 bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13 Mar  3 21:14 conf -> /etc/tomcat9/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1017 Jun  3  2019 default.template
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 17 10:37 etc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 17 10:37 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  133 Apr  1  2019 logrotate.template
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Mar  3 21:10 logs -> /var/lib/tomcat9/logs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   23 Mar  3 21:10 policy -> /var/lib/tomcat9/policy
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Feb 17 10:37 skel
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Mar  3 21:10 work -> /var/lib/tomcat9/work
root@doonas:/usr/share/tomcat9# ls -l /etc/tomcat9/
total 208
drwxrwxr-x 3 root tomcat   4096 Feb 18 13:26 Catalina
-rw-r----- 1 root tomcat   7483 Feb  4  2019 catalina.properties
-rw-r----- 1 root tomcat   1400 Jul  5  2017 context.xml
-rw-r----- 1 root tomcat   1149 Nov 21  2017 jaspic-providers.xml
-rw-r----- 1 root tomcat   2799 Jun 14  2019 logging.properties
drwxr-xr-x 2 root tomcat   4096 Feb 17 10:37 policy.d
-rw-r----- 1 root tomcat   7638 Feb 18 13:08 server.xml
-rw-r----- 1 root tomcat   2286 Feb 18 10:49 tomcat-users.xml
-rw-r----- 1 root tomcat 170202 Nov 18  2017 web.xml
root@doonas:/usr/share/tomcat9# ls -l /var/lib/tomcat9/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Mar  3 21:00 conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat tomcat 4096 Jun 14  2019 lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root     16 Mar  3 20:48 logs -> /var/log/tomcat9
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Feb 18 13:31 policy
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root     19 Mar  3 20:48 work -> /var/cache/tomcat9/
root@doonas:/usr/share/tomcat9# ls -l /etc/tomcat9/
Catalina/             context.xml           logging.properties    server.xml            web.xml
catalina.properties   jaspic-providers.xml  policy.d/             tomcat-users.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with Tomcat in an LXC container. Per [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62117816/3025856), I verified that all `ReadWritePath`s existed, but it still didn't help.

For some reason, enabling nesting in LXC helped ([source](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/apache2-service-failed-to-set-up-mount-namespacing-permission-denied.56871/)).

If you are using Proxmox, you can enable it like this:

```
pct set <id> -features nesting=1
```

Answer (score 5):

The error message doesn't originate from tomcat but from systemd. This unspecific message ([GitHub Issue 10972](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10972)) is fixed with Systemd 243.

What is the problem:
In the unit file is the option `ReadWritePath=` specified, but the folder/path doesn't exist.

To fix this run `systemctl cat tomcat9` to get a the complete content of the unit file and all maybe existing override files.
Then check all lines with `ReadWritePath=` and ensure the specified directory really exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Tomcat9. In my case, the boggus `ReadWritePaths` file path was defined in the following file:

```
/etc/systemd/system/tomcat9.service.d/override.conf
```

I removed the boggus path, then ran the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service tomcat9 restart
```